# Update item in state onClick ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

So, I have class Comopnent :

```
 state = {
    tokens: [
    {
      name: "first",
      value: 3
    },
    {
      name: "second",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      name: "third",
      value: 4
    }
  ]
  }
  handleClick = (name, id) => {
    const newState = this.state.tokens.map((token => {
    console.log(token.name)
    }))
  }
render() {
    const token = this.state.tokens;

    const tokenList = token.map(t => {
      return (
      <div value={t.name} onClick={() => this.handleClick(t.name, t.value)}>
        <img src=""/>

        </div>
      )
    })
```

What i need to do - after click - to subtract `1` from `value` clicked `token`.
So - ex. after click on "First" token i want his `value` equal `2`.
So far I've done just as much as the above.
I do not know how to go about it, i am new in ReactJS, so thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to find in your state in `tokens` array the object which has the same `name` as the argument passed in the onclick handler. Then you will have to change it's value - decrement it (`value--`) but you have to be aware that you can't mutate the state.

```
 handleClick = name => () => {
    const { tokens } = this.state;
    const clickedToken = tokens.find(token => token.name === name);
    clickedToken.value--;
    const clickedTokenIndex = tokens.indexOf(clickedToken);
    const newTokens = [
      ...tokens.slice(0, clickedTokenIndex),
      clickedToken,
      ...tokens.slice(clickedTokenIndex + 1)
    ];

    this.setState({ tokens: newTokens });
  };
```

Codesandbox link: **https://codesandbox.io/s/92yz34x97w**

Answer (score 1):

First, some things are wrong with your code.
1- You have an array of tokens, then you're mapping the list, but you don't have a key to index, this will cause weird behaviors, I improve your tokens list with keys now.

2.- You can handle the click and change the state of the tokens list, this will trigger a reload of the component.

```
state = {
    tokens: [
    {
      name: "first",
      value: 3,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "second",
      value: 2,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "third",
      value: 4,
      id: 3
    }
  ]
  }
  handleClick = (name, id) => {
        const { tokens} = this.state;
        const newState = tokens.map((token => {
                if(token.id === id) {
                        token.value--;

                }
        return token;
    }))
  }
render() {
    const token = this.state.tokens;

    const tokenList = token.map(t => {
      return (
      <div key={t.key} value={t.name} onClick={() => this.handleClick(t.name, t.value, t.key)}>
        <img src=""/>

        </div>
      )
    })
```